# Is there a way around Azure Active Directory Conditional Client Access

Tags: ios, outlook, azure-active-directory

My organization just blocked all native mail apps from accessing outlook, forcing us to use the outlook mobile app. They *probably* did this through conditional access through Azure AD, but I’m not 100% sure. I don’t want to do that, I like the native iOS app better. Are there any workarounds so I can start using the native app again?

Comment: If you want to use, you could ask your organization to enable it for your account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround to access Outlook with native mail apps if Outlook is blocked by a conditional access policy. That would be a huge security liability if there was a way to change an admin's access controls. As Sunny said, the best thing to do here is to ask the admin to enable this for your account.